# Connecting to Snowflake via Pyspark - Receiving Error Message

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

*(Submitting on behalf of a Snowflake User - any ideas leading to resolution would be GREATLY appreciated...)*

---

I am able to connect to snowflake via pyspark and am able to execute SQL query, but am getting error at `df.show()`.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Here is the error stack:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o43.showString.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/snowflake/client/jdbc/telemetry/TelemetryClient
at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.DefaultJDBCWrapper$DataBaseOperations.getTelemetry(SnowflakeJDBCWrapper.scala:385)
at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.io.StageReader$.sendEgressUsage(StageReader.scala:134)
at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.io.StageReader$.readFromStage(StageReader.scala:59)
at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.io.package$.readRDD(package.scala:39)
at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.SnowflakeRelation.getRDD(SnowflakeRelation.scala:147)
at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.SnowflakeRelation.buildScan(SnowflakeRelation.scala:132)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$10.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:293)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$10.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:293)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$pruneFilterProject$1.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:338)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$pruneFilterProject$1.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:337)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy.pruneFilterProjectRaw(DataSourceStrategy.scala:415)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy.pruneFilterProject(DataSourceStrategy.scala:333)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:289)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:63)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:63)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:439)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:78)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:67)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:93)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:72)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:68)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:77)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:77)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3254)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2489)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2703)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:254)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.telemetry.TelemetryClient
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 51 more
```

Comment: Can you please share the Scala, Spark and JDBC version you are using? Also, it would be helpful to know the JAVA_HOME, PATH and CLASSPATH variables you have set?

Comment: Will check with user. Standby for additional info...